# How to listen to a specific port and return 200 status

Tags: networking

How can I listen on my server on specific port and just return HTTP 200 status if someone tries to connect ?

Can `nc` be used to return HTTP status ?

Answer (score 4):

There's really no reason to use `nc` nowadays. With `socat`:

```
socat tcp-listen:12345,reuseaddr,fork \
   "exec:printf \'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n\'"
```

With `zsh` and its `ztcp` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/net/tcp
ztcp -ld 3 12345
while ztcp -ad 4 3; do
  print -u4 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r'
  ztcp -c 4
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`
will serve the current directory as a web page on port 8000 (the default port; ports below 1024 will require you to run with root (e.g. `sudo`) privileges).  A "200 OK" will be returned if you fetch from that port:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &
[1] 19976
$ Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...

$ wget localhost:8000
--2014-03-12 00:42:30--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8000... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2014 00:42:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
200 OK
Length: 178 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

100%[======================================>] 178         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-03-12 00:42:30 (16.0 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [178/178]

$ cat index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
<body>
<h2>Directory listing for /</h2>
<hr>
<ul>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
$
```